# Selection loses in datagrid when pressing Tab key

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid with multiple rows and If I select multiple rows and while editing a row if I press tab key I looses selection on the selected rows,Only current row is selected. I need all other rows to be selected without losing selection.

Please help.

Before Tab

[image]

After Tab

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Handle `Unselected` event of the DataGridRow. This is however just an idea, as it wont allow you to `Unselect` any row. But you can build upon this further, checking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  key pressed etc.

```
    void DataGridRow_Unselected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { row.IsSelected = true; });
        });
    }
```